# Description of for-break code

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, break

It is much appreciated if describe this code for each line

```
count = 20 
for x in range(0,10): 
      count = count - 1 
      if x == 2: break 
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 1: Variable Assignement, click [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/variables.html)

Line 2a: a for loop, click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Line 2b: range function, click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Line 3: Variable Assignment, see same link as Line 1

Line 4a: if statement, see same link as Line 2a

Line 4b: break function, see same link as Line 2a

Line 5: print function, click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)